# How do I display a full expression in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I am trying to use *sympy* in a Jupyter notebook to document and perform a series of mathematical cacluations in a reporducible way.

If I define the following:

```
from sympy import *

init_printing()
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")

x=y+z
x
```

then I can display the value of `x` (that is, `y+z`).

How do I display the full equation (`x=y+z`)?

Running `Eq(x,y+z)`, even with `evaluate=False`) returns the expression with the value of `x` substituted (`y+z=y+z`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you first declare `x` as a `sympy.Symbol`, once you perform the assignment `x=y+z`, `x` becomes an alias for `y+z`. Whenever you use `x` from that point after, `x` will be automatically translated by python as `y+z`.

If you insist on this workflow, you could use `Eq(S('x'),y+z)` to display the equation.

Comment: Is there a method off `x` that returns the equivalent of `S('x')`?

Comment: `S()` just converts a string to a sympy expression. You can just use `Eq(x, y + z)` here since `x` is already defined as a Symbol.

Comment: When I try this way it returns `False` instead of the expression itself.

Comment: @iury simoes-sousa: use `display(Eq(S('x'), y+z, evaluate=False))`. The full expression will be shown, not 'True' or 'False'

Answer (score 8):

I tried using `Eq(S('x'),y+z)`, also `Eq(S('x'),x)` and `sympy` keep returning a boolean variable.

So I found a way to display it using the `Ipython` built-in functions:

```
from sympy import *
from IPython.display import display, Math

init_printing()
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")

x=y+z
display(Math('x = '+latex(x)))
```

I think that this is a more general solution to the problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `KaTex parse error`.
Maybe my variable are badly named

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the answer, but for those just looking for a neat print of the right-hand-side of a function f(x,y,z,...), you can just do f.subs(x,x) like so:

```
import sympy as sp
x,y,z=sp.symbols('x,y,z')
f=x+2*y+3*sp.exp(z)
f.subs(x,x)
```